# SpriteKit Spin circle on center Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to spint a circular node on its center. I have been trying to following:

```
    var earthBase = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "earthBase")
    earthBase.position = CGPoint(x: 667, y: 20)
    earthBase.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: earthBase.texture!, size: earthBase.size)
    earthBase.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true
    earthBase.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 1
    earthBase.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    earthBase.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
    earthBase.name = "earthBase"
    earthBase.zPosition = 9
    addChild(earthBase)

    let spin = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat.pi, duration: 60)
    let spinForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spin)
    earthBase.run(spinForever)
```

When I do this it spins like the blue circle picture below but I want to to spin on its center like the green circle. I have tried changing the anchor point (none in the code above / default) but this will just move it farther away from the red dot.

Any thoughts?

[image: spin]

Comment: Can you post your earthbase image, I suspect the problem lies with it. I've taken your code and used with a circle image I have and it works perfectly

Comment: @RonMyschuk ..... You are right. I was using  circle I created in a graphics program on a larger canvas and for got to trim transparent pixels so the actual image was a rectangle... Thanks so much.

Comment: no problem, glad it helped